# Website not getting cookie info correctly and spamming reload

Tags: javascript, cookies, reload

I'm trying to define a version for my website so it can reload the resources if the versions don't match. The problem is that when I fetch the cookie, the cookie value is not returned. The result of this is that the website is in a constant state of reloading.

I made sure that the cookie was there and I tried using my functions in the console and setting the cookie manually.

Webpage:

```
var version = '1.0.0';
var cVersion = version == getCookie("version");
if(!cVersion) {
     setCookie("version", version, 1000);
     window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Cookies Script:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The website should reload and update the version number if they are different and do nothing if they are the same.

Comment: add `setCookie` method too

Comment: I added the setCookie method @AntihypeBird

Comment: Do you have any timeout or loop getting and setting the cookie?

Comment: No, what would that do? @AntihypeBird